# Variables cause error in c++

Tags: c++, mingw

In C++ when I try to use variables with cout it ill cive me an error pop up. I use eclipse as IDE and minGW as compiler. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 4;
    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

between the cout and num and num and endl; I got those to diamond breckets pointing left but they won't show here.

can anone please help me?

edit:

the error that pops up is(translated from dutch to english):

file.exe doesn't work anymore

A problem occurd causing the program to malfunction. The program will be closed and a notification wil be shown when there is a solution available.

Comment: why is you include empty? you should use iostream

Comment: If `cout << num << endl; ` prints `Hello World` then it's the end of days.

Comment: The error is not in the code you've shown us; that program will print `4`. You say you get an "error pop up"; update your question to show us the exact error message.

Comment: iostream was there I am thinking it is something with my compiler, but hello world works.

Comment: For me, your code prints `4`, which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 4):

rebuild your project : probably you 're running old version of your project

Comment: That didn't work. On my phone I have an app on wich it worked. I was thinking maybe a problem with the compiler but the basic hello world code works.

Comment: is your code exactly the same as you provided? Did you save this file? Did you really tried to rebuild the project?

Comment: Yes I did. as I said I think it is something with the compiler. and I did all of that

Comment: try to compile it from command line. Maybe you 're doing something wrong with Eclipse. I can't believe the problem is in MinGW

Comment: @miquelsmits If by "something with the compiler" you mean that you think it's a compiler bug, it's not. There is no way.

Comment: @cdhowie I didn't mean  a compiler bug but a error in the settings or path

Comment: I switched to another IDE and no it doesn't do it so probably something with my IDE or something